# Unknown error code during application install "-24"

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, 4.4-kitkat, moto-x

I just updated my Moto X to latest and greatest Android 4.4 KitKat (I even did full factory reset just to be sure) and now I'm trying to install [WhatsApp Messenger](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whatsapp) but unable to do so, I'm getting following error:

> Unknown error code during application install "-24"

Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

According to a [thread on AndroidCentral](http://forums.androidcentral.com/android-4-1-4-2-4-3-jelly-bean/292379-google-play-unkown-error-code-24-a.html), this is a problem with either...

- the app itself having trouble to update an already installed version (unlikely after a factory-reset) → uninstall first, then try a fresh install
- certificates not being handled properly → install from a different `.apk` (e.g. one from your backups, if you've made any, or from an alternative source)
- certificates (variant 2) → Go to *Settings→Apps*, select the "All" tab, scroll to *Google services framework*, tap the entry, "clear cache", "uninstall updates". Repeat the same for *Google Play Store*, then reboot, then try again

I didn't verify this (don't have the issue, so I didn't even have the chance to), but it sounds reasonable.

Additional sources on this error:

- [Unknown error code during application install: "- 24 "](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1992241) (XDA Developers)
- App description of the [PocketTool App](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.snowbound.pockettool.free):

> The -24 error is a killer. People think it is because of PocketTool when it is actually the device. You may want to include in the description that if they get the -24 error to reboot the device, then try reinstalling mcpe. If that doesn't work, uninstall all apps that could be used to modify the game, reboot, and try again. If even that doesn't work, the only other option I am aware of is to back up important things such as Kindle books, music, movies, and saved app data on something (I used my laptop) and do a factory reset. If they are on Jelly Bean, then they will get a -24 error if they try to reinstall mcpe after a failed mod install.
>
> Users had the same trouble [with Spotify](http://community.spotify.com/t5/Help-Android/Unknown-error-code-quot-24-quot/td-p/274896/page/2). A second factory-reset solved it.
>
> A [thread on Android-Hilfe.DE](http://www.handy-faq.de/forum/lg_optimus_l9_forum/285037-apps_google_play_store_mehr_installierbar_fehlercode_24_a.html) (German) again supports the first variant of my answer (remains of a previous install). Maybe your factory-reset did not complete cleanly.
>
> A [Google search on "google-play error-24"](https://www.google.com/search?q=google-play+error-24&ie=UTF-8) reveals even more sources.

Answer (score -1):

Download the app [Master Key multi-fix](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tungstwenty.xposed.masterkeydualfix). You can think of it as a plug in. But as soon as it is installed on your phone, you should be able to download the apps that had the error 24 notice. Hope this helps.

Comment: If you are not rooted and don't want to root your device, forget about this app because to install it a prerequisite is something called *Xposed Framework* (which in turn **requires root**)

Answer (score -1):

Use Titanium Backup to delete the orphan app data, then install the application again. That should fix the issue, but you'll lose all of the user data for that app.

Answer (score -1):

Dude, try this one, don't have to install an apk or reset your device, just delete via root explorer file named com.whatsapp in dir data/data/com.whatsapp
Then install your whatsapp again from playstore or apk directly

Comment: That would require the device to be rooted, which is not stated in the original question.

Answer (score -2):

Remove application and set to factory setting. Mine works now.

Comment: What to uninstall – after a factory-reset? A factory-reset includes removing all user-apps and their data, so there's nothing left to uninstall.